# How to write a boot sector binary file to a usb drive?

Tags: macos, assembly, binary, boot

I started writing a simple boot sector program. It ran in qemu and now I want to run it on my MacBook (Pro). 

What I already tried is to create an empty floppy disk image:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=1440
```

and put my 512k bin file in it:

```
dd if=bootload.bin of=disk.img conv=notrunc
```

I flashed it on an USB stick via Etcher, shutdown my Mac, pressed option and only MacintoshHD, but not my USB appeared.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Transferring the boot loader likely worked, however it is likely that your computer doesn't consider it bootable or doesn't support MBR based booting at all.  Does your bootloader work in a VM or on other systems?  Showing its source code might help, too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried it on a PC and it worked fine. So it seems to be a problem with my MacBook or Macs in general. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  I recall the same question having been asked before.  If you search Stack Overflow, you might find it.

Comment: Aren't Macs UEFI-only?

Comment: It's not a "problem" per-se, just that an Apple Macintosh is not compatible with legacy IBM-PC booting methods.  They both use x86 CPUs, but the firmware doesn't AFAIK do legacy BIOS MBR booting.  (I seem to remember something about bootcamp support being able to boot in legacy-BIOS mode to support old Windows versions that didn't have UEFI bootloaders.)  Anyway, the legacy MBR boot-sector thing is already obsoleted by UEFI and hasn't been particularly "close to the metal" for years, with some of the hardware (like PS/2 mouse/keyboard) just emulated by firmware.